# util.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, qt, umfpack

while connecting a library to QT after building the project I get the following error :

```
util.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol umfpack_di_symbolic referenced in function "public: void __cdecl util::Get_Initial_Solution(double *,class Mesh &)" (?Get_Initial_Solution@util@@QEAAXPEANAEAVMesh@@@Z)
```

I tried to rebuild the project and made sure that the versions of the library and the compiler I am using are compatible MSVC 2015 64 bit. i am referencing the library from the VCPKG "UMFPACK" using the builtin manager in QT creator as follows :

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR += "C:/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/lib"
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L"C:/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/lib/" -llibumfpack


INCLUDEPATH += "C:/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/include/suitesparse"
DEPENDPATH += "C:/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/include/suitesparse"
```

This is the get_initial_solution function that is throwing the error (some parts are removed from the code replaced by the three dots. just for simplicity.

```
void util::Get_Initial_Solution(double *Sol, Mesh &EHL)
{
.
.
.
 umfpack_di_symbolic(2*EHL.N_Nodes_2D,2*EHL.N_Nodes_2D,
                        Kee_colptr,Kee_rowind,Kee_nzval,&Symbolic, null,null);
    umfpack_di_numeric(Kee_colptr,Kee_rowind,Kee_nzval,Symbolic,&Numeric,null,null);
    umfpack_di_free_symbolic(&Symbolic);
    umfpack_di_solve(UMFPACK_A, Kee_colptr,Kee_rowind, Kee_nzval, x, rhs_hertz, Numeric, null, null);
    umfpack_di_free_numeric(&Numeric);
.
.
.
}
```

any idea what is causing this error ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)